# Is image segmentation required with the SURF algorithm?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I was reading about image segmentation, and I understood that it is the first step in image analysis. But I also read that if I am using SURF or SIFT to detect and extract features there is no need for segmentation. Is that true? Is there a need for segmentation if I am using SURF?

Comment: It isn't always as simple as you describe. Do you have a specific application in mind?

Comment: content based image retrieval.. I am using a surf tool to extract descriptors, I found that no segmentation in it since it is based on surf interest points .. That's why I was confused.. I was thinking that every image should be segmented before performing any operation on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dependency between segmentation and recognition is a bit more complex. Clearly, knowing which pixels of the image belong to your object makes recognition easier. However, this relationship works also in the other direction: knowing what is in the image makes it easier to do segmentation. However, for simplicity, I will only speak about a simple pipeline where segmentation is performed first (for instance based on some simple color model) and each of the segments is then processed.

Your question specifically asks about the SURF features. However, in this context, what is important is that SURF is a local descriptor, i.e. it describes small image patches around detected keypoints. Keypoints should be points in the image where information relevant to your recognition problem can be found (interesting parts of the image), but also points that can reliably be detected in a repeatable fashion on all images of objects belonging to the class of interest. As a result, a local descriptor only cares about the pixels around points selected by the keypoint detector and for each such keypoint extracts a small feature vector. On the other hand a global descriptor will consider all pixels within some area, typically a segment, or the whole image.

Therefore, to perform recognition in an image using a global descriptor, you need to first select the area (segment) from which you want your features to be extracted. These features would then be used to recognize what is the content of the segment. The situation is a bit different with a local descriptor, since it describes local patches that the keypoint detector determines as relevant. As a result, you get multiple feature vectors for multiple points in the image, even if you do not perform segmentation. Each of these feature vectors tells you something about the content of the image and you can try to assign each such local feature vector to a "class" and gather their statistics to understand the content of the image. Such simple model is called the [Bag-of-words model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model_in_computer_vision).

Comment: Perfect explanation! Thanks